# PHP unexpected end of file even when file is empty?

Tags: php, apache

Yes, I've searched around. I'd rather not use short tags, at all, so don't suggest it. I've had the strange issue of my Apache server claiming that PHP has reached an unexpected EOF even when the contents of the file are commented out. I've tried syntax checkers and they see nothing wrong. I'm absolutely confused as to why it'd be complaining, considering I can't have a missing } because I don't even have a {.

http://pastebin.com/7DmSFbJD
http://pastebin.com/xW3ckhD5 (I forgot to comment out the contents using /* */)

Comment: I don't get it.  You say that the files are all commented out but you show us two files with nothing commented out.  Note that you shouldn't put the trailing `?>` when there's nothing that comes after it for many reasons including this type of problem and security reasons.

Comment: The second one was supposed to be commented out and why exactly shouldn't I have a tailing ?>

Comment: I told you, to avoid having trailing garbage and for security.  Many hacker scripts will try to append `<?php badStuff(); ?> to your files but if you leave out the closing tag, it will issue an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In second file you're missing an additional `}` at the end. Your current last `}` is for *if clause*, not for function.

Comment: Absolutely? Then why wouldn't it work if I comment out the contents of the <?php ?> ?

Comment: @EvrythingMultimedia - Maybe you should copy/paste the code when it's commented out, then? Btw.. you should really learn how to format your code to make it more readable.

Comment: Serously? I've stared at this thing for so long, counted my brackets carefully, especially the last one, and I've missed a closing bracket... Consider this another repost. How did you spot it?

Comment: I noticed this with copy-paste into Notepad++. I made that when I press on any special symbol (like `}`) I would see the starting symbol. In your case, pressing on the last `}` would show for if clause, not for function. And pressing on `{` near function would show in white, meaning it has no ending.